# Query that excludes parents with "done" tasks

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015, tfs-workitem

I currently have a query set up in TFS 2015 with the following parameters:

---

- Work Item Type = [Any]

*AND*

- State <> Done

*AND*

- Assigned To = Derek Antrican

---

This is working well, but currently it will continue to show parent items that I have completed tasks for (because another tfs member has yet to complete a task for that parent). I would like to exclude parent items that have no more tasks assigned to me that are yet to be completed. So ending up with something like this:

---

- Work Item Type = Task

*AND*

- Work Item Type = Product Backlog,Bug **IF Child Assigned To = Derek Antrican *AND* Child State <> Done**

*AND*

- State <> Done

*AND*

- Assigned To = Derek Antrican

---

How do I implement the bold part above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want. You'll need to configure your query to be of type "Work Items and Direct Links" and then filter the children to be assigned to you (it's easier to use @me here):

[image]

**Note:** The separator for the "in" operator depends on your system settings. In my culture (Dutch), it's `;`, but it may be different for yours.

Comment: Thanks! Out of curiosity, is this possible with a Flat List (instead of "Work Items and Direct Links")?

Comment: No it's not possible with Flat list. Only with Direct Links or tree based queries.