# TFS Query for Features not 'Done' but all child User Stories are 'Done'

Tags: tfs, tfs-query

Anyone know how to write a query in TFS that will show any Features whose State is not 'DONE' but whose child User Stories or similar are 'DONE'?

Answer (score 0):

There is no default way to get Features not 'Done' but all child User Stories are 'Done' from a Query. You would achieve your requirement by using REST API to get parent/child work items from Wiql, and then check `state` for all child work items:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/wiql?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1

Or you can create a `Tree of work items` to return all Parent not 'Done', and then export the query to CSV to filter the Child manually:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Of course this can be done. [It's similar to what I've done here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36922259/736079).

Basically search for

```
Query Type: Work Items and Direct Links

Top level:
Work Item Type: Feature
State: <> Done

Child level:
Work Item Type: in(Bug, User Story)
State: <> Done

x Only show work items that don't have the specified link

Link types [Parent Child]
```

Comment: Your example will filter User Stories that contain one or more closed child's. But if you want to find User Stories only with all closed child's , there is no way to filter out them.

Comment: @ShamraiAleksander No it filters Features that have no childern in another state than done. The "Only show items that don't have the specified link" does that.

Comment: yes, you are right, that will work. However, your example`ll also return Features without any child work item because they also do not have (Bug, User Story) & State: <> Done ))